# Add image from mipmap in android drawable item part

Tags: android

Below is my drawable code. I want add image from mipmap in drawable item instead use of drawable.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <item android:drawable="@drawable/drawable_selected_indicator"
        android:state_selected="true"/>

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/drawable_default_indicator"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: what are you trying to do?? please be more specify

Comment: I want to use image in drawable but in drawable there is no option to use image in drawable item.

Comment: I think i figured it out: It seems an Android Studio Bug. When writing @mipmap/...  the JIT compiler will directly mark it red and tell you this can't work. Auto-complete STOPS too. If you write manually the exact path of the MIPMAP it WILL work and become green /valid. Bug in AA inmho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use @mipmap/filename to use an image from mipmap folder.

```
<item android:drawable="@mipmap/drawable_selected_indicator"
    android:state_selected="true"/>
```

According to this wiki-https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Working-with-the-ImageView

"Starting with Android 4.3, there is now an option to use the res/mipmap folder to store "mipmap" images. Mipmaps are most commonly used for application icons such as the launcher icon. To learn more about the benefits of mipmaps be sure to check out the mipmapping for drawables post.

Mipmap image resources can then be accessed using the @mipmap/ic_launcher notation in place of @drawable. Placing icons in mipmap folders (rather than drawable) is considered a best practice because they can often be used at resolutions different from the device’s current density. For example, an xxxhdpi app icon might be used on the launcher for an xxhdpi device."

Comment: Thanks for reply but we can't use mipmap image directly in our drawable part.
When we use drawable property in item it can only accept drawable..

Comment: Where exactly are you trying to add image? Drawable property accepts mipmap images, whether in code or xml.

Comment: i would like to put it in an xml-file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@mipmap/fileName` in your XML resources or `R.mipmap.fileName` in java/kotlin.

Comment: drawable have no option to access mipmap folder

Comment: They do. If you're facing an error its because of something else.

Comment: @shubhamagarwal any specific error while doing so ?